# ASP.NET Identity Batch Transaction

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

Been working alot with the new Identity system with ASP.NET MVC.

I keep running into issues, i try not to make my own workarounds due to it being new and under development.

However i am making a group management for it, due to having alot of roles giving access to different stuff, it would be easier to assign to groups than per single person (that or i have misunderstood functionality of Identity, as you assign role per controller).

But this requires batch transaction when doing a foreach, adding roles to the user from the group (As you wouldnt want a user hanging with 50% of the roles, its either error or 100%), i have seen that there is a AutoSaveChanges in the rolestore, but the rolestore adds it no matter what(usermanager aswell), and from the outside i gotta handle all theese exceptions for duplicates etc.

Have i missed something where i can add/remove/update in batch and later use some function that updates it all and handles the exceptions?

I have seen their newest sample, where they add multiple roles, this does not seem to use batch either.

Answer (score 1):

We are going to be adding something like `AddUserToRoles(param string[] roles)` in ASP.NET Identity 2.1, but the user manager should already be guarding against adding the user to the same role.

Comment: Sounds great, yea i think it is guarding, might have been something else, currently looking into it.
It makes it hard with no source code, so sometimes i guess and seperate things to see what happens, what it does, might have messed something up :)